# Auto re-size with divs

Tags: css, html

How can this iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.gamepuma.com/external.html?http://data.gamepuma.com/games/06/crash-bandicoot.swf"  width="600"  height="400"frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

be re-sized automatically by a div? The way I'm doing it's not working.

```css
.showgame {
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 40px;
}
```

```php
<div class="showgame">
<?php echo $row_GameData['strGame']; ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: if there is a link <a></a> inside the div then you can make up display : block on the <a> directly with width : 100% and height : 100% to fit the div

Comment: @John For future reference, you don't have a link here, you have an `iframe`. They are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your css selector from

```
.showgame
```

to

```
.showgame iframe
```

You can target the iframe directly in order to resize it.

If you'd rather keep all the styling on that wrapper div, you should be able to add this instead:

```
.showgame iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    border: 0;
    /*OR*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```